How do I interface multiple I2c devices in a single robot with raspberry Pi 5
I'm having some trouble with a robot hand that I am building. It is using servos for lateral movement of the fingers and solenoids for the vertical movement. Since there are 5 fingers on the hand I am using the Pca9685 as a pwm driver for the servos and the MCP23017 as an IO Expander for binary output to my solenoids. My controller is a raspberry pi 5, and the main issue I am having is with using the i2c devices, since both of these components will be interfaced with I2C. I am wanting to implement the robot with ros2_control, does anyone have experience with using multiple i2c devices with their robot that could help?
I had thought originally to create a centralized i2c bus manager class that both can use, but I still need individual plugins for the PCA and the MCP, how could I share that one object throughout the ROS2 control system?
Basically, I am wondering if a one has experience using ROS2/ros2_control to communicate with multiple i2c devices in a single robot using a Raspberry Pi5 and C++. I would to see an example, if possible. One of my main issues was when trying to connect to the bus peripheral if one device has already used it then an exception will be thrown. I would love to build a central class with a WriteRegisterByte method that I can just give it the I2c device address, the register to write to, and the value to write to the register and this class would be able to be used across multiple plugins. The sharing of this class is where I'm having difficulty and managing the I2c bus with dev/i2c-1 on my Pi.

Question: are you using the linux frameworks to work with I2C?  e.g. gpio, hwmon, iio...
The exception could come ff the device is taking by Linux and you still want to access it in user space.  Anyhow, for hardware and OS there should be no issue in using multiple I2C device on a bus.  As long as the have no duplicate addresses.

I was using this [repo] (https://github.com/rosblox/pca9685_ros2_control/tree/65aa0a2a0fe329fd49a098f12ba0cb858cdbe50e/pca9685_hardware_interface). However, the device (/dev/i2c-1) and the address (0x40) are hard coded, so I modified to to take those as a parameter. When I created a new object it was throwing an exception when calling the OpenBus method in I2CPeripheral. What I am planning to do now is use a shared pointer to create and object that calls the OpenBus method and then I will just use ConnectToPeripheral to set the device address before any read or writes.

I was just wondering why not using the Linux driver for the device (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/pwm/pwm-pca9685.c). I assume you will be able to use these driver in user space by the GPIO framework.  Also in Python, if you want.

Main reason was just because this component had a repo under the supported components on the official ros2_control website, so I figured I may as well use that. Then I found out that it seems to be suited for a single I2C component in the system as the bus and device address are hardcoded.

I don't know if my example will be helpful but I had to face a similar problem.
In my case, I needed to interface multiple light sensors (from Adafruit) that use I2C communication protocol with a TurtleBot4 robot (that has a Raspberry Pi 4 inside).
I followed these steps:

Check the pinout of your Raspberry Pi

Look for the pin that has alternative functions SDA and SCL. As an example, this is the link to check for the Raspberry Pi 4 board.
Find the two pins with the same SDA and SCL number as a possible alternative function. Once you find the right couple of SDAX, SCLX find the corresponding GPIO pins on your board and connect them to your sensor.


Enable the alternative functions for the GPIOs by following this link. You have to do this procedure for the pinout that doesn't have SDA, SCL as first alternative function.

The configuration.txt file should be located in /boot/firmware/config.txt.
As an example, I added the following line below # Config settings specific to arm64: dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=8,i2c_gpio_scl=9. Please pay attention that X means the number of the bus in SDA_X, that is the value that you have to set in previous line as bus=.


I used this library from Adafruit to handle multiple GPIOs. This is the code to read the data from multiple sensors:


import board
import adafruit_tcs34725
import time
import busio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from adafruit_extended_bus import ExtendedI2C as I2C
import adafruit_tcs34725

# sensor 1
i2c_1 = I2C(1) # Device is /dev/i2c-1
frontR_sensor = adafruit_tcs34725.TCS34725(i2c_1)

# sensor 2
i2c_4 = I2C(4) # Device is /dev/i2c-4
frontL_sensor = adafruit_tcs34725.TCS34725(i2c_4)

# sensor 3
i2c_5 = I2C(5) # Device is /dev/i2c-5
back_sensor = adafruit_tcs34725.TCS34725(i2c_5)

while True:
    print('Front right: {0}'.format(frontR_sensor.lux))
    print('Front left: {0}'.format(frontL_sensor.lux))
    print('Back: {0}'.format(back_sensor.lux))
    print("")
    time.sleep(1.0)


In terms of ros2_control it is difficult to interface the same communication device from two hardware components.
But why not interfacing all of them in one hardware component of type hardware_interface::SystemInterface like in our demos?

I think this may be the path that I take. In total the robot will have 4 separate physical hardware components running I2C communication, each with a unique address. I thought separate plugins would make it cleaner, but it seems to not be the case.
